# C3 Grouped Bar Graph Gaps

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, c3.js

I have a question regarding C3 Javascript library.

I have a graph that is a bar graph, and it has groups, so it appears as a bar with segments of multiple colors. I'm trying to get it to look nice when I print in black and white, and my colleagues don't want to modify the color scheme, so my next thought is to add about 2 pixels of spacing in between each segment of the bar.

I've searched all over the C3 examples, stack overflow, and tried a bunch of tricks with D3 myself for the last five or six days and I'm really stuck on this one.

Some things that I've tried is applying transforms/styles to the actual path elements that create the segments of the graph. So far, none of the styles that I've tried like margin or padding are respected, and I think this may just be the nature of path elements from what I've read, and I've been able to get translations and scales to be respected, but having issues getting the results I want:

With scale, the elements all crush together, they don't keep their actual dimensions on the page, so it just makes the overall graph smaller (and not to scale). With translations, I think I could get it to work with a D3 .each and have a different translation for each segment, but all together it obviously does not work either because they all move. I'm just looking for an elegant solution, but I am willing to fork over the time for that solution if there is no better way. So far I've been unsuccessful in finding a D3 or C3 solution.

I'm not too concerned with slight distortion of the data representation (i.e. shrinking each element by 2 pixels irrespective of size in reference to other elements, since it's really only a relative/approximate visualization.

```
    this._graph = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#graph',
        size: {
            height: 280
        },
        data: {
            x: 'comparisons',
            rows: graphData,
            type: 'bar',
            groups: [
                ['time1','time2','time3']
            ],
            colors: {
                'color1': this._green,
                'color2': this._pink,
                'color3': this._blue
            },
            labels: false,  //use to remove data labels
            order: null
        },
        transition: {
            duration: 0
        },
        onresized: function() {
            d3.selectAll("#graph .c3-texts .c3-text").each(function() {
                d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black');
            });
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                tick: {
                    outer: false,
                    centered: true
                }
            }, 
            y: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.75
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: false
        },
        transition: {
            duration: 0
        }
    });
```

[This is what the graph looks like approximately.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqGeW.png)

As I said, the only solution that I've been able to find a possibility with is to select the path elements with D3 and apply a function that has a reference to a variable in the parent context and apply a transformation of increasing translation each time, but it's obviously not an ideal way to do it.

I apologize in advance for my ignorance, I'm more of a C++ and bare metal developer, I'm very very new to JavaScript.

Thanks,
-R

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to apply a border at print time. This assumes that you have some control over the print event and are able to intercept it and apply styling before it actually prints.Does this violate the "no modifying the color scheme"?

Comment: Definitely doesn't violate it, I've been considering adding a print button to the form that can apply styling and launch the print dialog for the user. I'm still interested in other solutions, but I think that is a possibility.